# Filling an array of pointers in a function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

My program should fill up and show an array. It should also calculate average value in the array.

The program stops at this line:

```
cin >> *f1[j];
```

I think it's the problem line, but I could have made mistakes elsewhere.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

// prototypes
void add(int*f[],int h);      
void show(int*f[],int h);
int average(int*f[],int h);

int main()
{
    // getting size of a array
    cout << "How many numbers would you insert? : ";
    int i = 0;
    cin >> i;
    cout << endl;

    // the dinamic array
    int * arr = new int[i]; 

    // call functions
    add(&arr, i);
    show(&arr, i);
    average(&arr, i);

    // deleting the dinamic array
    delete[] arr;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

// declaring of the functions

// this function should fill up the array
void add(int* f1[], int h)
{
    for(int j = 0 ; j < h ; j++)
    {
        cout << "Insert " << j+1 << ". value : ";
        cin >> *f1[j]; //this should be the problem
        cout << endl;
    }

}

// this function should show the array
void show(int *f2[], int h)
{
    for(int j = 0 ; j < h ; j++)
    {
        cout << *f2[j] << ", ";
    }
}

// this function should should show average value of the array
int average(int *f3[], int h)
{
    int n = 0;
    for(int j = 0 ; j < h ; j++)
    {
        n += *f3[j];
    }
    n /= h;
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to:

- use `int* fX` in your function signatures
- drop the `&` referencing from your function calls (you already have a memory address stored in `arr` and there's no such thing as a memory address for another memory address)
- not use `*` dereferencing within your functions (you're already dereferencing the array with `[]` indexing)

http://pastebin.com/xY7A6JvE compiles and runs.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't referencing your arrays correctly. `p*` points to index `p[0]`

```
cout << *f2[j] << ", ";
```

should be

```
cout << f2[j] << ", ";
```

It compiles and runs with the edits I made.

http://ideone.com/DsxOOP

Also, You aren't taking any inputs.